# Transitions and backgrounds not mixing

Tags: html, css

I've only been testing this in `IE11/Win7` but since it doesn't work there it matters little to me if it works in any other browser. I need i solution that will work accross all browsers.

Im creating na html5 menu using only css. i have a background set for the dropdowns and am using :before to place na arrow in menu items that have a submenu. I also want the submenus to show up in a fade - and that's where my problems start.

At first i had the transition and the background set in the inner ul, and that worked - except :before counts as a child so the arrows would only show when the submenu was visible and that's not good.

So i placed a div around the inner ul and used :before in the div while i only fade the ul. Then the arrows would still show when the submenu wasn't visible, but when the menu was visible the background would show up only as a line accross the top (height 0 i guess)

So i placed the background in the div and now it workd except the fading only happens to the menu items themselfs and not the background.

here's a [jsfiddle with my last attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/a1zv8gxc/2/).

Is there a way i can make what i want? (show arrows always + background shows and fades in)

Comment: your arrow *IS* a background. Make css3 arrow without using background and it will not act like it. For instance you can make it with borders.

Comment: but if i place both arrow and background in ul and remove the div it works - only that when ul is hidden so is arrow

Comment: also the arrow is made with borders - did you even look at the jsfiddle?